# Align text with center of text as reference point

Tags: html, css

I have some text that I'm trying to align under a moving tick on a chart.  I can get it to stick with the tick by doing:

```
<div class="foo">Text</div>
.foo {
  width: $tick-location px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

but the problem is that this always aligns so that the end of the text is touching the tick.  What I really want is the center of the text to touch the tick.  I don't, however, know the size of the text ahead of time.

How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
----------|-----
     xxxxx

----------|-----
        xxxxx
```

The first is what I currently get.  The second is what I want.

Comment: Can you add a picture to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: `$tick-location`, trying something in php?

Comment: No I just put that in there as a token for the reader.  In actuality it's an Angular Dart variable set directly in the HTML template.

Comment: Chaitanya:  Will add

Comment: May I know what kind of tick you are using? Is it a styled div or an image?

Comment: Tick is a div.  I have a div chart, then under that a div tickContainer with dynamically spaced out divs for ticks, and then under that a div labelContainer that needs to have divs for labels that are spaced under the ticks.

Comment: The best I've been able to come up with is to do width: tickLocation * 2 and then do text-align: center.  But this is the worst kind of hack.

Comment: You could try tickLocation + foo/2

Comment: Unless there's some magic not made obvious, the `width: $tick-location px;` should fail because of the space between the (presumably) number and the "px"; syntax error. If you're willing to use a monospace font, you can use the `ch` measurement (the width of one zero char) to arrange dynamic text.

Comment: You can try `data-attribute` to get it with css or use `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Use transform for text centering. Better change the `left` instead of changing 'width'

```css
.foo {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  left:100px;
  /* here text's center will be at 100px; */
  /* left:$tick-location px; */
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be javascript solution for this.
https://jsfiddle.net/wingsofwind/mxspevy0/

```js
var b = $(".longerdiv").html().length;
var a = $(".foo").html().length;
$(".foo").offset({
  left: b * 3.02
});
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 20 px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="longerdiv">------------|------</div>
<div class="foo">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample of what you are trying. Hope this will work.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("animatedElement");
var s = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    var ePosition = e.offsetLeft;
    e.style.left = (ePosition + 10) + 'px';

}, 1000);
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timer); }, 45000);
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top:5px solid #000;
}
#animatedElement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
}
.mainDiv{
width:500px;
height:200px;
background-color:#e8dbff;
border:2px solid #000; 
}
.divWithTick{
width: 50px;
height:30px;
background-color:#fff;
}
.tick{
width:2%;
height:30px;
background-color:blue;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div id="animatedElement">
        <div class="divWithTick">
            <div class="tick"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="foo">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```